# Azure SQL Database - how to determine what index a Full Text Catalog contains

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL database and am trying to drop a full text catalog.  I get an error that says "Cannot drop full-text catalog because it contains a full-text index.

I've gone in and deleted every full-text index from the db, yet the error persists.  Is there a T-SQL statement I can run to see the exact index that this catalog supposedly contains?  Note that right-clicking on the full text catalog in SSMS has very limited options (not even Properties) when working in an Azure SQL database, hence the need for doing this in T-SQL.

Comment: this may help :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280918/how-to-find-full-text-indexing-on-database-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Many thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped .Try upvoting the answer there  that helped you.